# comparing with timeseries data of previous week google visualization api

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, charts, google-visualization

I want to compare current data with previous week data. Unfortunately, I couldn't get the right parameters to be passed to `google.visualization.data.join(data1,data2,'full',[[0,0]],[1],[1])` function.

Below is the code :

```
     $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/16r3qn').done(function (jsonData) {
                    var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data1.addColumn('timeofday','X');
            data1.addColumn('number','current');
            data2.addColumn('timeofday','X');
            data2.addColumn('number','previous');
            var hour; var min; var sec;var day;
            var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                              "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
                            ];

            var curtime = 0; var curcount = 0; var precount = 0;var pretime = 0;
             $.each(json.current.timeSeries, function(i,item){
                 curtime =  json.current.timeSeries[i].beginTimeSeconds;
                 curcount = json.current.timeSeries[i].inspectedCount;
                 date = new Date(curtime*1000);
                 hour = date.getHours(); min = date.getMinutes(); sec = date.getSeconds();
                 day = date.getDay()+' '+monthNames[date.getMonth()];
                 data1.addRows([[[hour,min,sec],curcount]]);
            });

            $.each(json.previous.timeSeries, function(i,item){
                 pretime = json.previous.timeSeries[i].beginTimeSeconds;
                 precount = json.previous.timeSeries[i].inspectedCount;
                 date = new Date(pretime*1000);
                 hour = date.getHours(); min = date.getMinutes(); sec = date.getSeconds();
                 day = date.getDay()+' '+monthNames[date.getMonth()];
                 data2.addRows([[[hour,min,sec],precount]]);
            });

            var joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(data1,data2,'full',[[0,0]],[1],[1]);


// ...etc. Rest of your code comes here, or is called from here.
      // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(joinedData, {width: 1400, height: 360});

}
```

**Graph to-be :**

[image: Correct image]

**Current graph :**

[image: Current incorrect image]

Help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: recommend using data type --> `'timeofday'` -- for the x-axis -- see [working with `'timeofday'`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/datesandtimes#working-with-timeofday)

Comment: Thanks @WhiteHat, timeofday does work, but I'm losing date now. Any chance I can have date along with the timeofday???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `'timeofday'` allows the values to align to the same x-axis range

in order to keep alignment and show the current week's dates on the x-axis,

build custom `ticks` using object notation,
each label will have a property for the value (`v:`) and the formatted value (`f:`)

in this case, the value will need to be --> `'timeofday'`
and the formatted value --> `'string'`

sample tick...

```
{
  v: new Date(curtime*1000),  // whatever you're using for 'timeofday'
  f: '04/03/2017'             // whatever you want to display on the x-axis
}
```

you could build in the *current* `$.each` snippet, no need to add any for *previous*...

```
var xTicks = [];
var formatDate = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
    pattern: 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'
});

$.each(jsonData.current.timeSeries, function(i,item){
    curtime =  jsonData.current.timeSeries[i].beginTimeSeconds;
    curcount = jsonData.current.timeSeries[i].inspectedCount;

    var xValue = {
        v: new Date(curtime*1000),
        f: formatDate.formatValue(new Date(curtime*1000))
    }
    xTicks.push(xValue);
    data1.addRows([[xValue,curcount]]);
});
```

using the object notation for the x value as well,
will allow the date to appear on the tooltip

add to options...

```
hAxis: {
  ticks: xTicks
}
```

note: depending on the pattern used --> `pattern: 'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'`
you may end up with duplicate `ticks`,
may need to test before adding to the `ticks` array

---

**EDIT**  -- see following snippet...

```
 $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/16r3qn').done(function (jsonData) {
        var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data1.addColumn('timeofday','X');
        data1.addColumn('number','current');
        data2.addColumn('timeofday','X');
        data2.addColumn('number','previous');
        var hour; var min; var sec;var day;
        var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
          "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
        ];

        // init ticks
        var xTicks = [];

        var curtime = 0; var curcount = 0; var precount = 0;var pretime = 0;
         $.each(json.current.timeSeries, function(i,item){
             curtime =  json.current.timeSeries[i].beginTimeSeconds;
             curcount = json.current.timeSeries[i].inspectedCount;
             date = new Date(curtime*1000);
             hour = date.getHours(); min = date.getMinutes(); sec = date.getSeconds();
             day = date.getDay()+' '+monthNames[date.getMonth()];

             // add tick
             xTicks.push({
               v: [hour,min,sec],
               f: day
             });

             data1.addRows([[[hour,min,sec],curcount]]);
        });

        $.each(json.previous.timeSeries, function(i,item){
             pretime = json.previous.timeSeries[i].beginTimeSeconds;
             precount = json.previous.timeSeries[i].inspectedCount;
             date = new Date(pretime*1000);
             hour = date.getHours(); min = date.getMinutes(); sec = date.getSeconds();
             day = date.getDay()+' '+monthNames[date.getMonth()];
             data2.addRows([[[hour,min,sec],precount]]);
        });

        var joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(data1,data2,'full',[[0,0]],[1],[1]);


  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(joinedData, {
    width: 1400,
    height: 360,

    // add ticks to chart
    hAxis: {
      ticks: xTicks
    }
  });

}
```

code added above...

```
        // init ticks
        var xTicks = [];

             // add tick
             xTicks.push({
               v: [hour,min,sec],
               f: day
             });

  chart.draw(joinedData, {
    width: 1400,
    height: 360,

    // add ticks to chart
    hAxis: {
      ticks: xTicks
    }
  });
```

---

**EDIT 2**

for comparing current week to previous,
recommend using the following option...

`focusTarget: 'category'`

this will combine the tooltips for each interval, so that you can see both values

you could also add a column for the variance using a calculated column in a data view
then hide the series from the chart,
but still allow it to appear in the tooltip

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    drawChart();
    $(window).resize(drawChart);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/eh5zf').done(function (json) {
    var data1 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data1.addColumn('timeofday','X');
    data1.addColumn('number','current');
    data2.addColumn('timeofday','X');
    data2.addColumn('number','previous');
    var hour; var min; var sec;var day;
    var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
      "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
    ];

    // init ticks
    var xTicks = [];

    var curtime = 0; var curcount = 0; var precount = 0;var pretime = 0;
     $.each(json.current.timeSeries, function(i,item){
         curtime =  json.current.timeSeries[i].beginTimeSeconds;
         curcount = json.current.timeSeries[i].inspectedCount;
         date = new Date(curtime*1000);
         hour = date.getHours(); min = date.getMinutes(); sec = date.getSeconds();
         day = date.getDay()+' '+monthNames[date.getMonth()];

         // add tick
         xTicks.push({
           v: [hour,min,sec]
         });

         data1.addRows([[[hour,min,sec],curcount]]);
    });

    $.each(json.previous.timeSeries, function(i,item){
         pretime = json.previous.timeSeries[i].beginTimeSeconds;
         precount = json.previous.timeSeries[i].inspectedCount;
         date = new Date(pretime*1000);
         hour = date.getHours(); min = date.getMinutes(); sec = date.getSeconds();
         day = date.getDay()+' '+monthNames[date.getMonth()];
         data2.addRows([[[hour,min,sec],precount]]);
    });

    var joinedData = google.visualization.data.join(data1,data2,'full',[[0,0]],[1],[1]);
    var dataView = new google.visualization.DataView(joinedData);
    dataView.setColumns([0, 1, 2, {
      calc: function (dt, row) {
        return dt.getValue(row, 1) - dt.getValue(row, 2)
      },
      type: 'number',
      label: 'variance'
    }]);


    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(dataView, {
      width: 1400,
      height: 360,
      // add ticks to chart
      hAxis: {
        ticks: xTicks
      },
      focusTarget: 'category',
      series: {
        2: {
          color: 'transparent',
          enableInteractivity: false,
          visibleInLegend: false
        }
      },
      vAxis: {
        viewWindow: {
          min: 0
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: many Thanks for this answer. Actually, there is some confusion here. I just need to compare today's data with last week's data. I don't want intermediate data to be a part of this comparison. timeofdata works fine but doesn't have date in it. Without timeofdata, I'm unable to compare the results. Hope I'm clear with my problem.

Comment: Also, I modified the datatype of current function from timeofday to string and ticks and it hasn't worked. Sorry, I'm new to google vis api, but I've to proceed with this flow... :(

Comment: https://pastebin.com/9Cf51BrP this is my current js file. Could you please let me know how to build custom `ticks` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139791/discussion-between-harshavmb-and-whitehat).

Comment: Have edited the code with the relevant code. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Hi @WhiteHat, Many Thanks for your answer. It is a shame to me that I'm not communicating well about the issue to an expert like you. The code shared by you presents the current date in x-axis than time which is not wanted. Could you please look at to-be graph, I need time on x-axis and count on y-axis but onmouse hover it should give the count at particular datetime interval. Hope, I'm clear now.
I sincerely thank you for your help. But, unfortunately, I'm not in a position to catch your tips and put them in practice. Shame on me.

Comment: okay.. https://api.myjson.com/bins/eh5zf my data.
If we extract the fields of `current` and `previous`, we get **Graph to-be** . Hope this helps. Thanks again.

Comment: very close. Thanks. How can I've have date also embedded in the label? Your first answer is close to the 2nd one except the variance bit. But, I'm interested in date as well along with the time.
Thanks

Comment: If you hover the mouse there you get time along with date. I've pasted the same image on this question. That's all I want.

Comment: I managed to change the labels from `current` and `previous` to have the date labels. 

I appreciate your help in this issue. You are awesome. Thanks a ton for your help. Keep rocking.. :)